# error message with openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have 42 excel files I am bringing into R using lapply and openxlsx.  The original excel files have 2 worksheets.  When I try to bring them in I get the following error message: 
  Error in read.xlsx.default(xlsxFile = x, sheet = 1) : 
  Workbook has no worksheets

even though I am specifying sheet=1.

When I go back into each file and delete the second spreadsheet I have no problem using the code to bring in all of the files.  Is this a bug with openxlsx?  I used the same code last year and did not have this problem.

Code:

```
  #bring in all files in directory

filenames <- list.files(path="S:/Adv/Scallop Central/2016 Scallop RSA/MAB Survey/2017 Data/Leg 1/2017 MAB SURVEY LEG 1 DATA/Inclinometer/Excel",pattern=".xlsx",full.names=T)
length(filenames)

info_deptemp <- lapply(filenames, function(x) openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile=x, sheet = 1))

info_deptemp2<-rbind.fill(info_deptemp)
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing the `S:` in your path parameter with the UNC path for the drive.

Comment: Did you discover if this was a bug? I have not found a problem in reading in files. I sometimes like to create a list of sheet names and use that for reading in. I have been thrown by hidden sheets which can be in index positions before the first visible sheet. `excel_sheets()` is the function giving names of all sheets in a file.